# MonoTouch.Dialog: Alignment of Text

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to right align the value entered in a cell:

```
    [Section]
    [Entry ("Nickname")]
    [Caption("Nick Name:")]
    [Alignment(UITextAlignment.Right)]
    string NickName;
```

But Left is used instead of Right? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alignment attribute only affects strings, it does not affect Entries.